# How to convert byte array into uint64_t for arduino led matrix

Tags: arduino

I saw this byte array into uint64_t conversion in this website for drawing letter **A** ;

I think this byte array into uint64_t conversion is reduce the code size and save the arduino IC code storage space also.

[image]

**Byte Array:**

```
const byte IMAGES[][8] = {
{
  B00011000,
  B00100100,
  B01000010,
  B01111110,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B01000010,
  B00000000
}};
```

**uint64_t array :**

```
const uint64_t IMAGES[] = {
  0x004242427e422418
};
```

**How to convert above showing byte array into uint64_t by looking above led matrix image without any tool(s) like [this website](http://xantorohara.github.io/led-matrix-editor/#004242427e422418) ?**

Comment: Why not use `uint64_t` in the first place and leave the rest to the compiler? A good compiler should optimise shifts for masking to single byte-writes. And don't spam tags. Arduino is definitively not C and not exactly C++. Also `B...` is no valid syntax (unless you have defined 256 symbolic constants or macros - you have not, have you?).

Answer (score 0):

**If it is little endian**

```
uint64_t IMAGE = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(byte) * 8); i++)
{
   IMAGE += ((uint64_t) byteIMAGE[i] & 0xffL) << (8 * i);
}
```

**If it is big endian**

```
uint64_t IMAGE = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(byte) * 8); i++)
{
   IMAGE = (IMAGE << 8) + (byteIMAGE[i] & 0xff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example can help you, the main function for conversion is 
`void displayImage(uint64_t image)`

```
// ARDUINO NANO
#include "LedControl.h"
LedControl lc = LedControl(4, 3, 2, 1);

const uint64_t IMAGES[] = {
  0x6666667e66663c00, // A
  0x3e66663e66663e00, // B
  0x3c66060606663c00  // C
};
const int IMAGES_LEN = sizeof(IMAGES) / sizeof(uint64_t);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lc.shutdown(0, false);
  lc.setIntensity(0, 8);
  lc.clearDisplay(0);
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < IMAGES_LEN; i++) {
    displayImage(IMAGES[i]);
    delay(1000);
  }
}

void displayImage(uint64_t image) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    byte row = (image >> i * 8) & 0xFF;
    Serial.println(row); // <- SHOW    
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      lc.setLed(0, i, j, bitRead(row, j));
    }
  }
  Serial.println("---");
}
```

`0x8040201008040201`

is equal to

```
  B10000000, // 1
  B01000000, // 2
  B00100000, // 4
  B00010000, // 8
  B00001000, // 16 
  B00000100, // 32
  B00000010, // 64
  B00000001  // 128
```

in the function **i** is the row **j** is the column and `bitRead(x,n)`
tells you is the led in the position **(i,j)** must be ON or OFF

```
// ex. for the value 128 on a generic row
for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    Serial.println( bitRead(128, j));    
}
```

[image]